# NPE при отработке выбора элемента списка

Tags: java, android-studio

Учусь работать с DrawerLayout. Для обработки выбора элемента списка создал класс DrawerItemClickListener наследующий от ListView.OnItemClickListener. Вот его код.

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        selectItem(position);
        setActionBarTitle(position);//28 строка
    }
};
private void selectItem(int position){
    ...
}
private void setActionBarTitle(int position){
    String title;
    if(position ==0){
        title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    } else{
        title = titles[position];
    }
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);//59 строка
}
```

Присваиваю слушателя в onCreate

```
ListView drawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

И при выборе элемента вылетает следующая ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.setActionBarTitle(MainActivity.java:59)
at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:19)
at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:28)
```

19 строчка

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

В чём здесь недочёт?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что программа не находит `ActionBar`. Попробуйте `getSupportActionBar()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше откажитесь от затеи использовать ActionBar(SupportActionBar), замените его на обычный layout и добавляйте в него все необходимые элементы.
P.S. С версией api actionBar может меняться, из-за чего Ваша верстка может полететь(в лучшем случае), а layout'ы никаких серьезных изменений не приобретут